# How to run a command on multiple servers without stopping it on one and it stop the whole command on every server on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

so the problem is, the code works fine but if I run the spam command on multiple servers, but stop it on a single one it stops spamming on all of them. I dont want that. Is there any way to fix that

```
import discord, pyautogui, time
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))



@client.command()
@commands.has_role('discordpy')
async def spam(ctx, *, my_id):
    print("it worked")
    time.sleep(5)
    x = 1
    global y
    y = 0

    while y != 1:
        @client.event
        async def on_message(message):
            if message.content == ".stop":
                y = 1
            await client.process_commands(message)
        myid = str(my_id)
        await ctx.channel.send(myid + " x " +str(x))
        print(x)
        x += 1
        print(y)
        time.sleep(0.5)






client.run('<Token>')
```

and just so you know i already tried out making a new command to stop the first one but to no avail

Comment: What you describe as a problem is IMHO the best feature of the script.

Comment: maybe, but I dont need it, not in this case atleast. Please help me if you can

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you store the server id and the status of the spam command (whether it's on or not) in an SQL database, so you can compare the ids in the database with the id of the server that the command was just called in and check if the status for that server's spam command is on or not.

If this proves to be too difficult, at the very least create a dictionary using the same principle.

An example with dicts (not recommended, especially with lots of servers):

```
# Changing the statuses
global statuses
statuses[message.guild.id] = value # "on"/ "off", True/False or whatever
```

```
# Checking the statuses
value = statuses[message.guild.id]
if value == "on":
    # Do stuff
else:
    # Don't do stuff
```

Make sure you declare it as a global to start with

```
global statuses
statuses
```

Comment: when I try and run it, it says "NameError: name 'value' is not defined"

Comment: so it would be really helpful if you could provide me the complete code along with what i provided, that would be really helpful But thanks a lot either way

Comment: are you on discord?

Comment: yeah more or less @justjude#2096